# Dynamical use of explicitly instantiated templates

Tags: c++, templates, explicit-instantiation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dynamic dispatching of template functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089284/dynamic-dispatching-of-template-functions)

I would like to use non-type templates to create grid cells with different memory footprints without having to use dynamically allocated memory on the heap, e.g.

```
template <int cell_size>
class myCell {...}
```

There is a finite number of cell sizes (approx. 10), thus I can easily instantiate all of them explicitly. However, which one of the cells are needed is not known at compile time but during runtime only.

I know that templates are a compile-time concept, but is there a way to use templated classes in this way, especially since I can guarantee that all necessary cell types are explicitly instantiated?

Answer (score 1):

You can use factory pattern, but you'll need a base class as a return type:

```
template <int cell_size>
class myCell : public cellBase {...}

struct CellFactory
{
   static cellBase* getCell(int cell_size)
   {
      switch (cell_size)
      {
         case 1:
            return new myCell<1>;
            break;
         //and so on
      }
   }
}
```

This works because you're telling the compiler which specializations it can expect. But I think that a better design exists for the underlying problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: By "better design", do you mean something else than the factory pattern, or something else than using templates?

Comment: @MichaelSchlottke something other than templates. Really depends on the actual problem.

Comment: I thought about using templates, as this would allow the compiler to optimize loops over the internal cell data. As far as I understand C++, if `cell_size` is just a member variable and used to allocate memory on the heap, all loops over the cell data would be execute as-is, since the compiler cannot make any deductions on the best optimization strategy at compile time.